# Não consigo adiconar a biblioteca react-navigation no meu projeto react-native!

Tags: linux, react-native, react-navigation, yarn

Estou tentando usar o yarn add react-navigation no meu projeto, mas eu não consigo adicionar a biblioteca fica aparecendo este erro. 
Já apaguei o package.lock.js, no entando aparece o erro ainda.

```
info fsevents@1.2.9: The platform "linux" is incompatible with this module.

info "fsevents@1.2.9" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. 

Excluding it from installation.

error An unexpected error occurred: "EACCES: permission denied, unlink '/home/lucas/App/mobile/node_modules/.yarn-integrity'".

info If you think this is a bug, please open a bug report with the information provided in "/home/lucas/App/mobile/yarn-error.log".

info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/add for documentation about this command.
```

Answer (score 0):

Delete a pasta `node_modules` e o `package.lock.js` denovo. Com o comando

```
sudo rm -r node_modules package.lock.js
```

Depois disso rode o yarn sem usar `sudo`. O seguinte comando

```
$ yarn install
```

O cifrão `$` é só para representar que deve ser executado como usuário comum.